# How do we do dynamic optimization with a scalar constant as the only free variable?

Tags: optimization, dynamical-systems, control-theory, optimal-control, hamilton-jacobi-equation

Suppose we have a dynamic optimization problem, such as to minimize

$$J(x_0,u) = \int_0^\infty \bigg(L(x,\dot{x}) +u^2 \bigg)dt$$
where
$$\dot{x} = f(x) + g(x)u, \quad x_0 = x(t=0)$$

To be clear, $x$ is a vector and $f$, $g$ are vector fields.

but $u(x) = u(a,x)$ where a is a constant scalar. For example,  $u = ax_1x_2$.

I am stuck while trying to use methods like writing the Hamilton-Jacobi-Bellman equation because it appears to leave $u$ a general function, but I want to specify it to be only of the parameter $a$, while holding $a$ constant. Is there a way to augment the equation such that $\dot{a} = 0$ or otherwise constrain this to solve the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the function $u$ fixed up to $a$? I.e., do you know that $u=ax_1x_2$ in advance?

Comment: @Arastas Yes, in this example, we know u = ax_1x_2, and just need to find optimal constant a. In another example of the same problem, u might take another form, but it's known a priori and at most we are trying to find optimal constants. Thanks

Comment: I am unsure if you need  HJB equation here. You basically have a scalar function $J(a)$ of the scalar variable $a$. Hopefully you can find the derivative of $J$ with respect to $a$?

Comment: @Arastas I appreciate the feedback. I believe that's exactly what I want to do, conceptually, but I'm not sure how to do it. Perhaps that's another question. The google term "functional derivative" is leading me to results about taking the derivative of a functional with respect to a function. If you know of a better search term so I can begin to teach myself this I would much appreciate it.